# ERROR: 42803: column "wage_histories.wage" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

I'm trying to migrate an application from SQLite to PostgreSQL, and now I have reached the point of re-expressing the queries that are valid in one and invalid in the other.

I have a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE wage_histories (
  uid INTEGER REFERENCES users ( id ) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
   start TEXT NOT NULL,
   wage INTEGER NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( uid, start )
);
```

It represents the wage of a user, over time. So, the wage of a user on a particular date is the value of the `wage` column in the row with our chosen `uid` and the highest `start` that is less than our chosen date.

I was able to express this in SQLite with the following query:

```sql
SELECT wage, MAX(start) FROM wage_histories WHERE start <= ? AND uid = ?
```

However in PostgreSQL this gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  42803: column "wage_histories.wage" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Is there something more succinct than the following?

```sql
SELECT wage FROM wage_histories WHERE uid = ? AND start = (SELECT MAX(start) FROM wage_histories WHERE uid = ? AND start <= ?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need one row:

```
SELECT wage 
FROM wage_histories 
WHERE uid = ? 
  AND start <= ? 
ORDER BY start DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This works. but I'm having problems with adapting it to the places where I need to get the full table of users

Comment: @pjstirling: if you need a different query, you should have asked a different question

Answer (score 1):

You want something like:

```
SELECT wage FROM
(
  SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uid, ORDER BY start DESC) as rn,
   wage
   WHERE start > ?
   AND uid = ?
) AS tab
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This will work nicely for all users if you take out the `AND uid = ?` clause, which, if I've understood your reply to @a_horse_with_no_name, is what you want?

Please tell us that you're not storing `DATE`s as `TEXT`?